# What is the kelipa of America?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, judaism

I understand nations have a *kelipa* attached to them, and, further, that these transfer over time (e.g. Russia is said to have the *kelipot* of both Greece and Edom).

What is the particular blend of *kelipa* unique to the U.S.? Does anyone have a source for this information?

Comment: Where did you read this?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Curious. Seems to have arrived via Meta and Biblical Hermeneutics and sat quietly for 30 days without comments or questions. Caution is advised.

Comment: Surely you've noticed that there are 50 states, and there are 50 gates. He who understands, understands.

Comment: Kindness is the klipa here. Immoral behaviors are shrouded in tolerance and love yet if you speak against them then you are intolerant and must be wrong.

Comment: I would have assumed (without being able to quote a mekor) that the ummos haolam are divided into the 70 nations. Today, identifying who is part of what umma is a bit difficult due to various mixing, but when we talk about ummos we shouldn't conflate them with modern countries. I.e. the people in America are not one umma mitzad halacha, but rather various ethnic groups within America belong to different ummos. I would assume that the distribution of klippos to various ummos follows this division into the 70 nations - not the 200+ modern countries.

Comment: וְעַתָּה שִׁמְעִי זֹאת עֲדִינָה הַיּוֹשֶׁבֶת לָבֶטַח הָאֹמְרָה בִּלְבָבָהּ אֲנִי וְאַפְסִי עוֹד

Answer (score 5):

Far be it for this Brit to criticise his favourite country after Israel: USA. Rather, this is something I heard from my American Rabbonim in Yeshiva, and have expanded slightly to fit with my own learning since.

They taught me that (and yes, it's a bit of a joke, but we all know Whose joke it is) America in Hebrew means "empty nation", אומה ריקה. What does that mean?

The answer is that they are the spiritual inheritors of Esav, whose *klipa* is the *klipa* of attraction to superficiality; the most basic function of the *yeitzer hara* (indeed *Sar shel Esav* is the same angel).

It's not that they are evil, not at all. It's just that Esav's way of approaching everything, even holiness, is to be superficial about it. In Chassidus, we learn this difference between Esav and Yaacov. Esav wanted to bring Moshiach quickly, by "sweeping all the dirt under the rug so the place looks clean". Yaacov said, you can't do that. The dirt is still there, on the inside, behind the superficial, where you can't see it, but the world is still unholy and the only way to make it holy is to take the time and hard work over millennia to make the world and it's inhabitants holy down to the essence.

Esav's ideological legacy is inherited by the West according to a few sources, and America is the center. In Torah, we say that the superficial is only there to serve the essential. We marry our spouse because of our spouse, not their looks. Once we are into the person, then, *because **they** are important*, everything about them becomes important *as a result*. Every hair on their head.

Esav's *klipa* (literally "peel", the most superficial part of the fruit), is that there may or may not be an "essential" side to things; an unseen depth that is the reality at the core, but their focus is on the superficial.

For example, a Torah true Jew will never find "fashion" interesting, it's so nakedly superficial, so the children of Israel have never put any importance into it at all, and in fact distance themselves from it to a large degree. Esav on the other hand is absolutely fine with it. If a person wants to make fashion mega important or even dedicate their whole life to it; *power to them*! he says. *It's your *right*, it's a *free country*, there's nothing wrong with it, go nuts! Don't let anyone tell you that you can't be a good person because of that!*

It's funny, because sometimes you can see the incoherence of this. *Racism is an evil of the superficial: a person is judged by their superficial traits and that's considered absolute abhorrent! Why? Because it's superficial!* A person is more than his skin colour, says Esav (as you can see, his *klipa* isn't opposed to goodness or Moshiach - is very much in favour actually)! However, without realising it, they will then take the victim of racism they just defended and the perpetrators they just educated and encourage them all to just go ahead and follow their heart and find one of the many "not evil" superficialities to make into their god. *Become a movie star, or a collector of video games, or just settle for a nice house in a nice neighborhood and that's your whole life accomplished. #YOLO; be obsessed with external beauty, sex, parties, money, cars, vacations, superficial love and relationships, entertainment, tasty food, etc etc they say, just don't be racist or sexist! Those are superficial!*

In Torah, we make the deep and the essential the main, and unashamedly define superficiality as "emptiness". It's the only way to fix the world. The body has a soul and it is more real than the body. The soul is delicate and sensitive and must be carefully focused on, in a very personal intimate way, to protect it and cultivate it. It can take a lot of time and effort and usually involves self regulation and denial, limited distractions by the superficialities of life; exposure to them in a controlled way after being raised to appreciate them in their correct context - which is never one that is simply following the heart.

Now, does this apply to America and the west? Well, it's too simple and narrow an explanation to account for the huge diversity of nations, states and individuals in this huge region, but perhaps we can see that there's more than a kernel of truth in it, in the bigger picture.

Comment: Interesting piece Reb Kaii! Never heard of the Hebrew meaning behind America. "Empty nation" - maybe there's a special reason why there are many Jewish brothers living in the US today, to "transform the sparks of evil to the sparks of holiness", to "fill the empty nation with holiness", but that's just my thought :)

Comment: @Shmuel Thanks! I think you are right. Isn't it cool how the question "What is the purpose of galus" is being linked to this by the algorithm?

Comment: did not notice that, how interesting!

Comment: Esav and Ishmael will definitely be redeemed.

Comment: How does america in hebrew mean empty? Which word in hebrew are you referring to? Chutz laaretz? Artzot habrit? (Funny that you're a brit and america is called the land of the brit :)

Comment: @larry909 אומה ריקה (sound it out). Now, make the same joke about Russia

Comment: I wonder if you couldn't apply to the entire Western civilisation. Why American only? More extreme materialists?

Comment: @mbloch thanks for the question. I didn't fully address it but I hinted. Of course, this is a very speculative answer, so in order to further the speculation, it seems that American culture and lifestyle flow downstream to much of the West. Also, America is the strongest western country and takes the lead in a lot of politics (e.g. NATO). There's so much to say, but I don't think it's too hard to accept USA as a "representative" of the west in a spiritual sense. Counter arguments would be welcome in a chat if anyone wishes to go further into it.

Comment: If you really want to entertain this question, then remember that the United States had the two Presidents Bush 41 and his son 43. That was George miGeorge (גוג מגוג). See Ezekiel 38:2, 38:3 and 39:1 for details. It states explicitly what the klippot for that nation are: Meshech and Tuval. (משך ותבל) These two klippot are associated with sexual perversion and excessive greed. This was why the Scroll of Gog miGog was written in both Hebrew and English by the Nascent Sanhedrin many years ago and sent by Rabbi Steinzaltz to President Bush.

Comment: @YaacovDeane that works (even if it goes against Rashi) but then why did neither Gulf War result in the Geulah?

Comment: @יהושעק how do you know it didnt? The repercussions from that war are still being felt

Comment: @YaacovDeane do you think my answer is wrong then? Or are you answering it in a more specific/different way?

Comment: The generic, geographic term "America" is referring to the continents on the bottom half of the globe, opposite & corresponding to the Holy Land (North America, Central America and South America possibly included in the term איי הים), not any particular nation and people which occupies some part of that territory. The proper name for the United States (what the OP is asking about specifically) is ארצות הברית.  It is no mistake that the name of something in Lashon HaKodesh connects to its essence. In this case emphasizing, how "G-d's Will" רצון is connected to "the Covenant" הברית.

Comment: @יהושעק Like is found in many traditional sources discussing this subject, there are 3 parts to the war of Gog MiGog. Like Rabbi Moshe Chaim Luzzato explains in Tikkunim Chadashim, the first part of that war would be characterized by the דם ואש ותימרות עשן (Blood, Fire-from the Sun & Date Palms of Smoke-Mushroom Clouds). That 1st stage was about Hiroshima & Nagasaki which also involved the United States. The 2nd stage was the Gulf Wars which also involved 9/11, the subject of Zohar, parshat Shemot 7a and parshat Balak 212b. Take note that all this is considered the "Days of Moshiach" in Torah.

Comment: @יהושעק If you would like more detail concerning Hiroshima and Nagasaki from Joel 3:3, you might find search results for the term, "White Light/Black Rain" and Japan of interest. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Light/Black_Rain:_The_Destruction_of_Hiroshima_and_Nagasaki

Comment: http://www.farallonfilms.com/#/white-lightblack-rain/

Comment: @YaacovDeane still not sure if you answered my question. Also, all this stuff would be very well suited in my Gog UmaGog question. There are so many theories about these things, based on sources and Torah. I admire your confidence, and I consider your scholarship flawless, but how can you be convinced you've got it right? Might be nice to see you write your explanation in full somewhere. Feel free to email me or answer a related question

Comment: @RabbiKaii Note the "United States" (the nation) of America (the continent). But just to carry the term for the continent "America" a step further in Lashon HaKodesh, It would more appropriately be written עמריקא. This is a compound word from Omer עמר, as in counting the Omer & bringing the Omer offering, a dry measure volume (Shemot 16:22, VaYikra 23:11), and the final letters יק״א, which with the kollel is associated with יבק, the term in Torah with how G-d connects the Heavens and the Earth via the 3 specific names, אהיה, יהוה, אדני which is gematria 112, emphasizing the nation & continent.

Comment: @RabbiKaii Regarding the 2nd stage of the War of Gog miGog subject, see the Rebbe's comments in regard to the Gulf War. It wasn't by accident that the Rebbe said then, עוד חזון למועד. If you have a question about this specific idea, ask Manis. He definitely addresses that in videos.

Comment: Regarding your statements in your 4th paragraph regarding Yaacov and Eisav and who wanted to bring Moshiach quickly, who didn't (and was not prepared), and how it is taught in Chassidut, you should review the Alter Rebbe's teachings in Torah Ohr to parshat VaYishlach, the Chassidishe parsha. The Alter Rebbe teaches that it was, in fact, Yaacov who was ready and pushing Eisav prematurely. That was the purpose of his gifts to Eisav.

Comment: @YaacovDeane that's the way I heard it from Reb Manis! Perhaps discuss with him?

Comment: @RabbiKaii It sounds like you misunderstood what Manis was saying. If you have any question, please check the source from the Alter Rebbe in Torah Ohr cited above. It is very clear what it states.

Comment: @YaacovDeane that's one possibility. Another is that we are misunderstanding each other and there are two teachings that need to be resolved. I believe he says it clearly in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wV1SV8YmR0. I can't check now though, so I apolgise if this is not the right one. This is another possibility: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCk_AAIu-E8

Comment: Like I said above, if you want to know what "Chassidut teaches" of this subject, learn the Alter Rebbe in Torah Ohr, the Chassidisher parsha. That is exactly what the Rebbe says in many, many Ma'amarim. Manis is a shaliach, a legal agent halachically, of the Rebbe. His authority is dependent upon adhering to and follow the teachings from the Rebbe, the one who sent him. For you, please look at the link I have provided to the Alter Rebbe's printed text, not a YouTube video of a talk not based on a text. Eisav murdered and raped. He was not "ready". Yaacov was "ready".

Comment: @YaacovDeane I will get back to you. I have studied the idea you bring, seen it in Sichot, etc. I just don't immediately jump to Rabbi Friedman having made something up (I've also spoken to some chassidim and they have heard of the idea too, and told me roughly where to find it). I will find his source and get back to you in time. Thanks for your efforts